# Could i use my own Gazebo world as RL Environment for a turtlebot3? how?

Tags: ros, gazebo, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!                                                                                                                                                                              I've just created my own Maze with Gazebo Simulator, and im wandering if i could use it as a Simulation Environment for my RL-project while using OpenAI and ROS. I think that OpenAI Pakage can provide different Environment, but is it possible to use my own ? if so, then i'd be so grateful to know how.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401663/could-i-use-my-own-gazebo-world-as-rl-environment-for-a-turtlebot3?-how?/) by [Belghiti](https://answers.ros.org/users/99615/belghiti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2022-05-31

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-05-31**:
Can you add links to these packages? I think they sound interesting. Thanks!

**Comment by [Belghiti](https://answers.ros.org/users/99615/belghiti/) on 2022-05-31**:
@ljaniec, yes with pleasure! https://github.com/edowson/openai_ros. and i hope im not wrong...

**Comment by [Hedwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/86750/hedwin/) on 2023-06-04**:
Hi, how did you manage to speed up the simulation ?
I triedadding the following lines to my .world but it didn't changes anything

<max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
<real_time_update_rate>1000</real_time_update_rate>

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2023-06-05**:
Can you speed up the simulation in the Gazebo window? Or is it not enough?

**Comment by [Hedwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/86750/hedwin/) on 2023-06-06**:
Thanks ! Indeed I was able to modify those two parameters in my simulation and it changes the simulation speed. However, the problem came from the values I choose. According to https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=physics_params&cat=physics :
"real_time_update_rate: This is the frequency at which the simulation time steps are advanced. The default value in Gazebo is 1000 Hz. Multiplying with the default max_step_size of 0.001 seconds gives a real_time_factor of 1"

But setting max_step_size to 0.01 instead of 0.001 broke the robot so I guess I have to find the right parameters now !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this tutorial "Using Gazebo for Reinforcement Learning" can be helpful:

- https://karelics.fi/using-gazebo-for-reinforcement-learning/

and this:

- https://karelics.fi/from-video-game-to-real-robot/
- https://erepo.uef.fi/handle/123456789/21382

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Belghiti](https://answers.ros.org/users/99615/belghiti/) on 2022-06-02**:
@ljaniec, I am indeed deeply grateful for this great help. the Hero we all need but don't deserve :D